# How to take only one value for each field in @RequestBody in java in SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring

I have a Class

```
public class TestClass {
  private String name;
  private String id;
  private String accountID;
}
```

Post Method:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/testclass", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public void create(@RequestBody TestClass testClass) {
  //implementation using testClass
}
```

This works fine until the body in the request is as requires but
When a POST call with body having multiple values of a variable, the @RequestBody takes the last given value of the variable.
For Example:

```
POST call Body: 
{
"name":"qwerty",
"id":"qw123"
"accountID":"111111",
"accountID":"222222",
"accountID":"333333",
"accountID":"444444"
}
```

then the `testClass` object has values name=qwerty,id=qw123,accountID=444444

Thus, this allows any kind of request with any number of values in the body to be processed.
Is it possible to identify this multiple values in the request so as to validate all the request prior to the implementation?

I.e I want the request to fail before reaching the code. I want to process the request only if it has single values. Also, it's not just about the given variables, the request may contain other variables as well , but the requestbody simply ignores it and takes the relevant variables alone. I want it to fail in that case too –

Comment: Change `accountID` to a List

Comment: Why don't you make `List<String> accountID;`?

Comment: I don't think the question is how to access all of those values but instead how to validate the JSON in the request to be sure that every key appears only once before processing it.

Comment: So you want the request to **fail** before reaching your code, if the request body has multiple entries, did I understand that correctly?

Comment: @BenjaminMaurer That's at least how I interpret the question. To be precise: if the request body has multiple entries _for the same key_.

Comment: Put @Valid before your parameter in the method.

Comment: yes, I want the request to fail before reaching the code. I want to process the request only if it has single values.    Also, it's not just about the given variables, the request may contain other variables as well , but the requestbody simply ignores it and take the relevent variables alone.  I want it fail in that case too

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Jackson to validate duplicated properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37152629/how-to-use-jackson-to-validate-duplicated-properties)

Comment: @Arnaud thanks for pointing out the usage of Jackson. But since I am not doing any conversion from JSON to object, I could not use Jackson for validation. The requestbody itself converts the JSON into the object. That's where i am stuck as i have no control over what values the object should take and when it should fail.  This is what i understand according to my knowledge, if it is still possible to use the Jackson for this, please let me know.

Comment: Spring uses Jackson, and you have ways to customize the Jackson mapper it will use, see here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7854030/configuring-objectmapper-in-spring

Comment: @Arnaud Thanks for the help, customized Jackson mapper worked!