# How to detect duplicate keys during map construction from JSON in clojure

Tags: json, clojure

I am using http://clojure.github.io/data.json/ `read-str` to read swagger (https://openapis.org/specification)
documents for semantic validation.  One of the things to validate is no duplicate paths.
For example:

```
/foo/{bar}/baz
```

is a duplicate of:

```
/foo/{dup}/baz
```

However, if the swagger file contains two "literal" identical paths:

```
/foo/bar/baz : ...
...
/foo/bar/baz : ...
```

When I use `read-str`, the last one "overwrites" the first one, so I can't see
the duplicate - it is just dropped.

Is there a way to use `clojure.data.json` to complain on duplicate keys?

Or is there some other library I can use?

Comment: You will likely have to drop down into Java interop and use something like Jackson.  See [Jackson detection of duplicate JSON POJO properties and Map keys](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23781637/jackson-detection-of-duplicate-json-pojo-properties-and-map-keys)

Answer (score 1):

unfortunately, no. This library does not offer a hook at that level out of the box. It lets you add hooks to validate the individual keys and the individual values in isolation and not in a context where it can tell if the keys is already in the map. It just calls `assoc` so you get the Clojure behaviour by default.

```
(assoc! result out-key out-value)
```

You can copy the `read-object` function from json.clj in that project and add a validator to the `result` transient map. This would be brittle though.

Comment: Yeah, I tried adding a `:value-fn`, but by the time it is called the overwrite has already happened.